# Is adding a public method to a public class a breaking change?

Tags: c#, versioning

For example a `Person` that has only one `Age` method:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age()
    {
        return 6;
    }
}
```

A `Height()` method is added.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age()
    {
        return 6;
    }
    public int Height()
    {
        return 6;
    }
}
```

Is that a breaking change? Pay attention that `Person` is not sealed.

Comment: What is your understanding of a *breaking change*?

Comment: Quite basic. a breaking change may change some clients behavior

Comment: [Every public change is a breaking change](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/01/09/every-public-change-is-a-breaking-change/)

Comment: I note that the spelling in English is -- bizarrely -- `Height` -- and that it is a little strange for height and age to be integers. Surely `Height` should be a `double` representing meters, and `Age` should be a `TimeSpan`, right? And they probably should be properties.

Comment: @Eric Lippert after waiting for a while for you to answer any of my question I'm extremely happy I missed spell `Height`.

Comment: @Dolev:  :)  English has completely stupid spelling rules. Good question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr;**

Eric Lippert is right, again..

Thanks to Tim Schmelter's comment with the link to Eric Lippert's [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/01/09/every-public-change-is-a-breaking-change/), I've changed my original answer.

Adding a public method or property to an existing class is **potentially** a breaking change. Probably not, **but it might be!**

**The longer version**

A breaking change means you are changing the public API of your type in such a way that existing code working with the current API will no longer be able to compile.

Obvious breaking changes are removing public members, or altering them in such a way that the code using your class can't be compiled anymore. 
Such changes might be (a partial list!):

- adding a non-optional argument to an existing method.*
- changing the data type of an argument of an existing method to a data type that's not a base type of the original argument
- changing the data type of a property to a data type that is not deriving from the original data type
- changing the return type of a method to a type that's not derived from the original type

As Eric demonstrates, even adding a new public method is *potentially* a breaking change, and just like in the breaking overload he blogged about, so does changing types of properties or arguments to a more specific types (meaning derived from original types) might also be a breaking change, for the exact same reasons.

However, Eric also points out that such scenarios are so specific and unlikely, that it's probably safe to assume you will not encounter them.

> This particular "flavour" of breaking change is an odd one in that it makes almost every possible change to the surface area of a type into a potential breaking change, while at the same time being such an obviously contrived and unlikely scenario that no "real world" developers are likely to run into it.

---

*While we are on the subject of breaking changes, changing an optional argument default value is also a potential breaking change - since optional arguments works by injecting the default value to the calling method as an argument passed to the method that have an optional argument. Changing the default value means you have to recompile everything that uses the method.

Comment: `A breaking change means you are changing the public API of your type in such a way that existing code working with the current API will no longer be able to compile.` This doesn't necessarily mean compile-time change. Binary compatibility should also be part of it : pre-existing compiled binaries should still work as it was.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the links Zohar and Tim; Zohar's answer is correct. In case it is not completely clear what the breaking scenario is, consider:

```
public sealed class Person
{
  public TimeSpan Age { get; set; }
}
public sealed class Building
{
  public double Height { get; set; }
}
public sealed class Weird 
{
  public static void M(Func<Person, double> f) {}
  public static void M(Func<Building, double> f) {}
  public static void N() {
    M(x => x.Height);
  }
}
```

This program compiles without error because overload resolution correctly deduces that `x` must be `Building`.  But if we add property `public double Height {get; set;}` to `Person`, then `Weird.N` contains an ambiguity error because we cannot know which is intended to be the type of `x`.

In practice, this sort of breaking change is rare enough that we explicitly decided to not consider it important when designing language features and libraries.

Comment: Does the .NET runtime library allow adding properties/methods to an existing sealed class?

Answer (score 5):

It will be a breaking change if any derived class already declares a `Hight` property and has "treat warnings as errors" turned on.

The change will produce a [CS0108 warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0108) (which becomes an error) unless or until the owner of this class adds the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 4):

To add possible breaking changes to the list, here is a rather nasty one:

Company A publishes its grandiose new class `Foo`. Company B loves the new stuff but misses some functionality that it decides to implement via en extension method tailored exactly to their needs:

```
namespace A {
     public class Foo { ... } }

namespace B {
     static class Extensions {
         public static string Frob(this Foo foo) { .... } } }
```

Company A realizes that it could do better and decides to upgrade `Foo` with some new functionality and decides to add a new method `string Frob()` with a general purpose implementation.

Company A publishes the updated library and Company B happily updates its software with the new version. Everything compiles fine... but a breaking change happened just the same; `foo.Frob()` is now resolved to `Foo.Frob()` and not to the extension method `Extensions.Frob(this Foo foo)`.

Comment: ...And to make matters worst, clients of company B only figures out tgat data was currupted a few weeks after the update... Nasty indeed...