# Service reference breaks when web service changes

Tags: c#, .net, service-reference

I have a "public API" web service project which I'm also accessing from another project via service reference. One of the web service's methods returns an array of a custom object, but if the API is upgraded and the custom object changes in some way (such as an extra property) I would expect the rest of the object to map fine and the new property just comes up blank, but instead the whole object fails to map. Does anyone know of any way to get around that?

Comment: Related, though not a dupe: [Is adding a public method to a public class a breaking change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49170904/is-adding-a-public-method-to-a-public-class-a-breaking-change)

Comment: Wait, where was the field added? In the API (i.e. the backend in this scenario), right? So what are you expecting your frontend (the consumer of the API) to do? Expect the old type, receive the new type, but map it to the old type as best as it can?

Comment: @Flater basically, yes. If I have a custom address object with fields like AddressNameNumber, AddressStreet, AddressTown, AddressCountry, AddressPostcode, and then I add AddressCity at a later date, I would think it could be made smart enough to map the old fields fine and just leave AddressCity at a default value. Apparently I'm mistaken!

Comment: `leave AddressCity at a default value` Do you mean when sending data from your consumer to your API? Well, since the consumer doesn't know about that field, why would you expect that the consumer would somehow know that it needs to add this particular field to the serialized data it sends?

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear about that. These are the responses I'm talking about, not the requests. The request never changes and just passes in a unique address identifier, it's the response which has a new field my project doesn't really care about.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any change in the Web Service, you will have to update the reference and build the project.

Comment: Is there absolutely no way of making it dynamic? Even if I use HttpWebRequest rather than web services and just map the data onto a custom object from the XML returned? Having a separate version of my project for each version of the API that could possibly be out in production seems like a complete nightmare.

Comment: By using HttpWebRequest, you can make an attempt. In this case, no strongly typed contracts are created except your own logic. I would suggest in your case move away from web service to Rest APIs if possible.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but how do Rest API's get away from this issue?

Comment: Rest API's have better support for Json which is more lenient with types.

Comment: OK that's good news, thanks. Unfortunately it's not up to me but hopefully we can move over to Rest in the not-too-distance future!